# Openvas-cli (OMP) not working

Tags: debian, openvas

I'm about to perform a script to automatically execute task.

The problem is :
When I'm writing this :
`omp -u user -w password -G -i` (whatever the last args)
I'm getting this error : `Failed to acquire the socket.`

So I think this is because I have not mentionned the server.
So when I'm doing this :
`omp -h localhost -p 443 -u user -w password -G -i` (whatever the last args)
I'm not having error, but there is an infinite loading.

So whatever the args I'm passing, I just can't use omp :(.

Is anyone know how to resolve this issue ?

I'm using the latest OpenVas distrib (OpenVas 9) and OpenVas-CLI is 1.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using the wrong port. Based on this doc(http://www.openvas.org/src-doc/openvas-cli/index.html) the default omp port is `9390`.

Try this:

```
omp --port=9390 --host=localhost --username=admin --password=UUID-PASSWD -G -i
```

Comment: Thank you ! I solved by starting opevasmd like this : openvasmd -a 0.0.0.0 -p 9390 et now omp is going fine :).

Comment: Happy to help. There is some code in here that may help you, I use omp with python and dump the results in elasticsearch. https://github.com/CriticalSecurity/python-perception. Look in `perception/classes/openvas`

Comment: Thank you for the link :).
I'm using python too to automate scans.